# Spring boot custom error page for 404

Tags: spring-boot

i wish to have custom 404 error page .I have velocity in my classpath but I don't want to use velocity view resolver
Below is my code

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={VelocityAutoConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan
public class Application {
Properties props = new Properties();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
}
```

i am not able to redirect all the 404 to my some html in resource directory.

Please assist

P.S It work if i am use velocityresolver and have error.vm in template directory.

Thanks ans regards

Answer (score 11):

You can provide a `EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer` and add your (e.g. static) error pages there.  See [Error Handling](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-error-handling) in the spring boot docs.  E.g:

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer() {
        return new EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer() {
            @Override
            public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
                container.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/404.html"));
            }
        };
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, though I tried the same thing and it didn't worked before(spent couple of hours banging my head on wall).         I guess you need a static folder to have htmls, i was having my 404.html in resources folder.

Comment: Yes static files have to be in the static folder.  But you can configure other places where you want your static files served from and you can also use a view here (instead of a static file).

Comment: @cfrick, how would you use a view instead of a static file?

Comment: Is `EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer` available in other libraries? etc. Spring MVC?

Answer (score 8):

As of Spring Boot `1.4.x`:

> If you want to display a custom HTML error page for a given status code, you can add a file to an `/error` folder. Error pages can either be static HTML (i.e. added under any of the static resource folders) or built using templates. The name of the file should be the exact status code (e.g. `404`) or a series mask (e.g. `5xx`).
>
> For example, to map `404` to a static HTML file, your folder structure would look like this:
>
> ```
> src/
>  +- main/
>      +- java/
>      |   + <source code>
>      +- resources/
>          +- public/
>              +- error/
>              |   +- 404.html
>              +- <other public assets>
> ```
>
> To map all `5xx` errors using a freemarker template, you’d have a structure like this:
>
> ```
> src/
>  +- main/
>      +- java/
>      |   + <source code>
>      +- resources/
>          +- template/
>              +- error/
>              |   +- 5xx.ftl
>              +- <other templates>
> ```

Checkout the [Spring Boot documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-error-handling-custom-error-pages) for more detailed discussion.