# Vaadin 7 + Spring Boot error page

Tags: spring, spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin7

I have integrated Vaadin 7 and Spring Boot. Right now I need to implement error view in order to substitute standard page, for example:

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Mon May 23 10:50:20 EEST 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).
Access is denied
```

It should be implemented as a separated Vaadin UI or in some other way ? Could you please provide me with an implementation of such page ? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring boot custom error page for 404](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26214675/spring-boot-custom-error-page-for-404) - also https://github.com/peholmst/vaadin4spring/issues/285

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work also with spring-boot and vaadin and nothing is special there. You can see possible configuration here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html

So you can configure a `@ControllerAdvice` to do the Trick!

Hope that helps! :)

Regards