# http error handling using ErrorController

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, freemarker

I am using httpBasic with AuthenticationEntryPoint to verify if the person is authenticated or not. I would like to send a custom error page through the ErrorOcntroller interface. Instead of just returning a string.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {
        response.addHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=" + getRealmName());
        response.response.sendRedirect("/error");
    }
```

My error controller class

```
@Controller
public class RequestErrorController implements ErrorController {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RequestErrorController.class);
    @RequestMapping("/error")
    public String handleError(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Object status = request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_STATUS_CODE);

        //log.error("Error 404 generated for this request ->"+ request.getRequestURI());
        if (status != null) {
            int statusCode = Integer.parseInt(status.toString());

            if(statusCode == HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value()) {
                return "error-401";
            }
            if(statusCode == HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value()) {
                return "error-404";
            }
            else if(statusCode == HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value()) {
                return "error-403";
            }
            else if(statusCode == HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value()) {
                return "The request did not match any end-point. Please revise the request signature and parameters type. ";
            }
            // on va rajouter bad request vue que 500 est deja la
        }
        return "error";
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return "/error";
    }
}
```

The problem is It is simply not getting to this controller.

I have made an update to my code and finally getting to the controller.
Now the problem is , it is looking for the freemake template:

```
2021-08-06 18:03:42,240 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-2] c.n.j.A.RequestInterceptor [RequestInterceptor.java:122] returning true
0 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG freemarker.cache  - Couldn't find template in cache for "error.ftlh"("en_US", UTF-8, parsed); will try to load it.
2 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG freemarker.cache  - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("error_en_US.ftlh"): Not found
3 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG freemarker.cache  - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("error_en.ftlh"): Not found
3 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG freemarker.cache  - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("error.ftlh"): Not found
2021-08-06 18:03:42,272 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.f.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter [CommonsRequestLoggingFilter.java:55] REQUEST DATA : GET /error]
```

Comment: maybe with `@ResponseBody` associated to `handleError`?

Comment: It is not getting there.

Answer (score 0):

An explanation of how to create custom error pages
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-custom-error-page
They just used plain .HTML pages

You probably use a freemaker dependency in your project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>**spring-boot-starter-freemarker**</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Have you tried to create error.ftlh, error-401.ftlh, error-403.ftlh, and error-404.ftlh templates inside your resources folder?

Comment: I do use freemake. I don't want to freemake for custom error pages.

Comment: I see. Have you tried creating error pages as HTML files like error.html, error-404.html etc? Maybe if you provide HTML pages than freemaker will not be used?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a similar stack discussion
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26221980/16571215

There is another solution there that seems to be promising.